# How to center `<span>` font awesome icons vertically with one another

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have multiple font awesome icons that I want to align vertically, as so

```
#############################
icon icon icon icon icon icon
#############################

<div class="announcement-card-body modal-body card border-0">
        <span class="info fa fa-info-circle"></span>
        <span class="star fas fa-star fa-lg "></span>
 </div>
```

I have already tried using `vertical-align: middle`

This is what I have tried based on comments but no luck

```
.info{
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}
 .star {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And also

```
.info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;;
}

.star {
    display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Try [fixed width icons](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons)

Comment: try `display: flex; flex-direction: row`

Comment: use flexbox `.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}`

Comment: Can you include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Scrimothy didnt work

Comment: @Michael tried it but no luck, see edit

Comment: @NilsKähler tried all through but nothing

Comment: your `display: flex` needs to be on the container of the icons

Comment: the flex should be in the `div` the "parent" then it will work.

Comment: -The selectors you are using in the flex code you implemented from the comments are not matching any element in the html code.
Those selector would match elements with classes "start" and "info", like this <div class="star"></div> or <div class="info another-random-class">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `display: flex` and `align-items: center` must be on the container

```
.announcement-card-body {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}

<div class="announcement-card-body modal-body card border-0">
  <span class="info fa fa-info-circle"></span>
  <span class="star fas fa-star fa-lg "></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That centers them horizontally within the container above and below one another. How do I align them side by side, as in my example?

Comment: Didi you remove the other flex styles you had on the individual icons? This answer should be correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by align side-by-side. You may want `justify-content: space-between` if you're trying to spread them out across your container. If you want them all to be the same width, you may want to put `flex: 1 0 auto; text-align: center;` on each icon.

Comment: this solution does work, the `card` class in the container was the issue